# Sorting LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

How can I sort a LinkedHashMap based on its values given that the LinkedHashMap contains of String and Integer. So I need to sort it based on the Values which are Integers. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have to use a LinkedHashMap? TreeMap might help?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780541/how-to-sort-hash-map

Comment: Oh. I see. Didn't bother to read the comments. ^_^

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is now quite a bit easier with Java 8 streams: you don't need the intermediate map to sort:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .forEach(entry -> ... );
```

Comment: What's in those three dots?

Comment: Those three dots represent whatever you want to do with the sorted values. It might be to call another method, print them, collect them in a different map - whatever your problem requires.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted and so highly ratet? It does not answer how to sort the map itself. It just tells how to process the contents of the map in a specific order.

Comment: @Guardian667 Maps themselves cannot be sorted in place. That's quite clear in the documentation for the interface though some maps make guarantees of their order. I suspect OP and upvoters realised that and understood 'sorting the map based on its values' to mean using the entries in order of their values. No other interpretation of the question makes any sense.

Comment: That's a valid suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 81):

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries =
  new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
  public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> a, Map.Entry<String, Integer> b){
    return a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());
  }
});
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : entries) {
  sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Well dammit, I was writing the exact same code! :) Except for the last part, I don't think OP actually needs to have them back in a map.

Comment: Nice answer. I had to sort in descending order so, added a -ve sign while returning value from the Comparator.

Comment: Prefer to switch the order of the arguments; negation doesnt always work if the original compareTo returned Integer.MIN_VALUE.

Comment: That is, write b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue()).

Comment: You don't need to change the comparator. You can use `Collections.reverseOrder(comparator)` which makes the meaning more obvious.

Answer (score 4):

`LinkedHashMap` just maintains insertion order. If you want to sort based on value, you may need to write your own `comparator`.

Comment: I don't think you need to write your own comparator. `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` should generate one for you. And it can be reversed by `Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())`.

Comment: @sprinter: What if the value is type of any custom object?

Comment: @Nambari Either have that type implement `Comparable` or provide a customer `Comparator` to `Map.Entry.comparingByValue`.

Comment: @sprinter: Exactly, that is what this answer was about.

Comment: and how would you use that comparator? are you providing a different solutions from the others

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class HashMapTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Integer> map=new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

    map.put("a", 11);
    map.put("B", 12);
    map.put("c", 3);
    map.put("d", 4);
    map.put("e", 5);
    map.put("f", 6);
    map.put("g", 7);
    map.put("h", 8);
    map.put("i", 9);
    map.put("j", 3);
    map.put("k", 2);
    map.put("l", 1);

    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new 
    ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
            Collections.sort(entries,new CustomizedHashMap());


            Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, 
   Integer>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : entries) {
              sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
              System.out.print( sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), 
          entry.getValue())+"  ");
            }
     }
    }

 class CustomizedHashMap implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return -o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
  }

}
```