# How to make a generic ValueComparator for sorting multiple HashMaps?

Tags: java, reflection, collections, comparator, parameterized

I first started working with a single HashMap such as:

```
private static Map<Broker, Integer> brokerSalesCountList = new HashMap<Broker, Integer>();
```

and used

```
private static ValueComparator4Broker bvc =  new ValueComparator4Broker(brokerSalesCountList);
private static TreeMap<Broker,Integer> sortedbrokerSalesCountList  = new TreeMap<Broker,Integer>(bvc);

sortedbrokerSalesCountList.putAll(brokerSalesCountList);
```

Here's my Value Comparator code:

```
public class ValueComparator4Broker implements Comparator<Broker> {

    Map<Broker, Integer> base;
    public ValueComparator4Broker(Map<Broker, Integer> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Broker a, Broker b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:** Now I have more than 2 new Hash Maps to be sorted the same way, and rather than duplicating the code for *ValueComparator4Broker* class, I want to make a single generic and parameterized *ValueComparator* class which can be used by all new *HashMap*s:

```
private static Map<Area, Integer> areaBrokerCountList = new HashMap<Area, Integer>();
private static Map<Area, Integer> areaSalesTotalList = new HashMap<Area, Integer>();
```

I tried something like the following, but the code is erroneous and does not even accept the key object of my HashMap to be substituted for *Type*. Any help to refine the approach and a code example would be greatly appreciated:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;

public class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Type> {  
    Map<Type, Integer> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<Type, Integer> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Type a, Type b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }

}
```

Comment: Your comparator has to return `0`, or you won't be able to _use_ the resulting `Map`.  Trying to warp a value comparator into a `TreeMap` is just plain a bad idea.  Try just keeping a sorted entry collection, or using a `LinkedHashMap` after sorting the entries and inserting them in that order.

Comment: @Louis, you seem to be making a very invaluable suggestion, however as to the "how" part, I'm totally in the dark. Any example will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12184443/869736

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so good at cold typing Generic code but here's the idea:

Use the class this way:

```
Map<Broker, Integer> brokerSalesCountList = new HashMap<Broker, Integer>();

private static ValueComparator<Broker> bvc =  new ValueComparator<Broker>(brokerSalesCountList);
```

Define the class here:

```
public class ValueComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {  
    Map<T, Integer> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<T, Integer> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T a, T b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }

}
```