# Sorting LinkedHashMaps based on its value

Tags: java

I'm struggling o the following task:
I'm adding Characters and Integers (the int is the number of apperances of a certain character) to a LinkedHashMap (yes, unfortunatly I have to use this).

How can i print it out orderer?

```
 LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap();
 int a=7;
 int b=6;
 int c=9;
 map.put('a', a);
 map.put('b', b);
 map.put('c', c);
```

Output should look like this:

```
 c 9
 a 7
 b 6
```

Comment: can you explain what you have tried? There are tons of duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184378/sorting-linkedhashmap

Comment: Can you store primitive data types in Maps, I believe you can store only objects. you have wrapper classes to do that.

Comment: @saikumar - Read about *AutoBoxing*.

Comment: Because c has the highest value and b the lowest

Comment: And I've seen the duplicates, but I don't want to sort it into another List I just want to print it out in the format Key(blankspace) value  in a ordered way

Comment: @Stunt - You can't sort *hash based structures*. You will have to either change your data structure to `TreeMap`which accepts a `Comparator` or get the entry set, parse key value and then print.

Comment: @TheLostMind Could you write me down how the parsing of key and values for entry sets is done?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the map to a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which can be sorted. The default map is sorted by the natural ordering of the keys, which should be sufficient for you as you use Integer...

```
TreeMap tm = new TreeMap( map );
```

Comment: This will sort only in *Natural Order*. Which is not what the OP wants

Comment: There is also a constructor for TreeMap which takes a comparator: TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator). Implementing a comparator that sorts Integers descending instead of ascending should be easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

How try like this,

The method to sort **Map based on Value DESC**

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> mapSortedByValues(Map<Character, Integer> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> entryList = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(entryList,
            new Comparator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e1, Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e2) {
                    return (e1.getValue()).compareTo(e2.getValue());
                }
            }
    );
    Collections.reverse(entryList); //Reverse value DESC
    Map<Character, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : entryList)
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Testing value sorting;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
    map.put('a', 7);
    map.put('b', 9);
    map.put('c', 6);

    Map sortedMap = mapSortedByValues(map);
    System.out.println(sortedMap);
}
```

Will output

```
{c=9, a=7, b=6}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the map in a list.
2. Sort the list.
3. Put the list back to map.
4. Resign the sorted map to your map.

Here's the code

```
 List list =new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>( map.entrySet() );

 Collections.sort(list, (Map.Entry o1, Map.Entry o2) ->{
                       return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue())
                 });

 Map result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
 for (Map.Entry entry : list){
    result.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
 }

 map = result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
    .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue()));
```

This reverses the normal compareTo to make the order reverse. If you can use the natural ordering then it's a bit simpler:

```
.sorted(Map.Entry::comparingByValue)
```