# How to sort HashMap of arrays by integer key Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` of arrays of strings identified by integers as key. I want to sort this HashMap by keys.

My hashmap  : `HashMap<Integer, String[]> htab = new HashMap<>();`

I tried the `TreeMap` solution but it doesn't have a compatible constructor of my values (`String[]`): 
`Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>((Comparator<? super Integer>) htab);`

Example of a set of my HashMap:

```
21 : {"2","3","5","10","0"}
```

Comment: If the values are **arrays** of strings, use `Map<Integer, String[]> = new TreeMap<>();` instead of `Map<Integer, String>`.

Comment: Yes, or:  Map<Integer,String[]> tmap = new TreeMap<Integer,String[]>(Htab)

Comment: Or you can use **LinkedHashMap** and sort the instance of LinkedHashMap. This is a sample for how to sort a LinkedHashMap by value and sort by keys is the same. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184378/sorting-linkedhashmap)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `(Comparator<? super Integer>)` part for your TreeMap. Also you have used `String` instead of `String[]` in your declaration. This code will work:

```
SortedMap<Integer, String[]> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String[]>(Htab);
```

Or alternatively you can declare Htab as a TreeMap instead of a HashMap to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the keys you may use a TreeSet or a TreeMap as follows. The keys are naturally sorted, i.e. the sorting is defined by the Integer class.

```
Map<Integer, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();

Set<Integer> naturallySortedKeys = new TreeSet<>(map.keySet());
Map<Integer, String[]> naturallySortedMap = new TreeMap<>(map);
```

Comment: They are looking for a sorted map not a sorted key set.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I just edited my answer to provide both.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the `TreeMap` with the `HashMap` as a parameter.

```
public void test() {
    Map<Integer, String[]> htab = new HashMap<>();
    String[] a = {"a", "3", "5", "10", "0"};
    htab.put(21, a);
    String[] b = {"b", "3", "5", "10", "0"};
    htab.put(210, b);
    String[] c = {"c", "3", "5", "10", "0"};
    htab.put(2, c);
    Map<Integer, String[]> sorted = new TreeMap<>(htab);
    System.out.println(htab);
    System.out.println(sorted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TreeMap as per the comment written by jesper.

```
    Map<Integer, String[]> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String[]>();
    map.put(21, new String[] {"abc","bcde", "regweger"});
    map.put(43, new String[] {"dbc","bgercde", "reggweer"});
    map.put(31, new String[] {"afbc","bcdrge", "rewgwger"});
    map.put(5, new String[] {"abgc","bcdee", "regwesgr"});
    map.put(98, new String[] {"abhhc","bc3gde", "regrer"});
    map.put(11, new String[] {"awqbc","bc33de", "frgeger"});

    System.out.println(map.toString());
```

You will find the to string prints out the elements in ascending order of key value.