# Why LinkedHashMap can't sort HashMap while TreeMap can?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, treemap, linkedhashmap

I'm trying to sort `HashMap`'s output using `LinkedHashMap`and `TreeMap`.

When I use `TreeMap` to sort out `HashMap` it works like a charm.

```
        Map<Integer, String> hMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        hMap.put(40, "d");
        hMap.put(10, "a");
        hMap.put(30, "c");
        hMap.put(20, "b");

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("before");

        for (Map.Entry m1 : hMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(m1.getKey() + " " + m1.getValue() + "    ");
        }

        System.out.println("after");

        Map<Integer, String> hTree = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(hMap);
        for (Map.Entry m2 : hTree.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(m2.getKey() + " " + m2.getValue() + "    ");
        }
```

Output :
`before
20 b    40 d    10 a    30 c

after
10 a    20 b    30 c    40 d`

But when I try with `LinkedHashMap` to sort `HashMap` it doesn't seems to work.

```
        Map<Integer, String> hMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        hMap.put(10, "a");
        hMap.put(20, "b");
        hMap.put(30, "c");
        hMap.put(40, "d");

        System.out.println("before");

        for (Map.Entry m1 : hMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(m1.getKey() + " " + m1.getValue() + "    ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("after");

        LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> lhMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>(hMap);

        Iterator it = lhMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            System.out.print(me.getKey() + " " + me.getValue()+"   ");
        }
```

Output :

```
before
20 b    40 d    10 a    30 c     
after
20 b   40 d   10 a   30 c
```

Can anyone tell me why is this sorting doesn't work? Is that becuase `LinkedHashMap` is filtering the `HashMap`? 

If it is why `TreeMap` is immune to that issue?

Thank you

Comment: What gave you the impression that a `LinkedHashMap` sorts anything?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it sort through insertion order.

Comment: And you got the insertion order as output.

Comment: @LuCio. No it is not. Insertion order is `10,20,30,40`. Output is `20,40,10,30`. Please take a look at the second example

Comment: @pippilongstocking that's the insertion order into the HashMap. Not the insertion order into the LinkedHashMap. You pass a HashMap to the LinkedHashMap constructor. So this constructor iterates though the HashMap (which has no ordering), and inserts each element of the HashMap into the LinkedHashMap. And as you see, you get the same order as in the HashMap, which shows that the insertion order is preserved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LinkedHashMap` maintains the insertion order. This means that if you pass to the constructor a sorted `Map`, or put the keys in the `LinkedHashMap` in sorted order, it will remain sorted.

However, you pass a `HashMap` to the `LinkedHashMap` constructor, and it's not sorted (since `HashMap` has no ordering). Therefore the resulting `LinkedHashMap` is also not ordered.

On the other hand, `TreeMap` keeps the keys sorted, so the order in which you put the keys in the `TreeMap` (which in your example is determined by the order the keys are encountered while iterating over the source `HashMap`) doesn't matter - the resulting `Map` will always be sorted.

Answer (score 6):

The JavaDoc of [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) says:

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the
>   order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

By creating the `LinkedHashMap` by inserting a `HashMap`, the `LinkedHashMap` preserves the order of the `HashMap hMap`.

The JavaDoc of the [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) says:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular,

Thus the not guaranteed order of the `HashMap hMap` is preserved by `LinkedHashMap lhMap`.

On the other hand you created the `TreeMap hTree` using the [default constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#%3Cinit%3E()). That means you created "*a new, empty tree map, using the natural ordering of its keys.*". Therefore `hTree` is sorted on every insertion. An insertion implies an ordering.

Regarding the `LinkedHashMap` it does no ordering on its own.

---

Further reading: [Sorting LinkedHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184378/sorting-linkedhashmap)

Answer (score 5):

1) Treemap will sort the element by using natural order by default.

2) Linkedhasmap will maintain the insertion order like list.

Answer (score 3):

TreeMap sorts by the compareTo implemented by keys (or a comparator function passed on construction, comparing keys).
LinkedHashMap only keeps order of insertion so I guess when you create it using a hash map the insertion order is the same as when you iterate over the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap doesn't keep the sort for the keys. What's more, note that it's not guarded that an HashMap instance shows the (k-v) sequences identically when it's size changes due to the load factor.

The "sort" means for LinkedHashMap is not about the sort by key value comparison. Instead, it means the insert order or the access order.

insert order <2,"A">, <1,"B"> ,<3,"C">

iterate order as insert order: <2,"A">, <1,"B"> ,<3,"C">

Then assume that implementing operation of accessing(get/put) <1,"B">
iterate order as access order: <2,"A">, <3,"C">,<1,"B">