# Sorting Hashmap by values from High to low

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to sort a hashmap that has a structure of  by the value from high to Low.

I have created a function below to sort the data.

```
public static void SortDataHighToLow (Map <String, Integer> UnsortedMap){
    List <Integer> list = new ArrayList(UnsortedMap.keySet());
    Collections.sort(list,new Comparator <Integer>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {

            return arg0-arg1;
        }
    });

    Map <String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (Integer keys: list){
        sortedMap.put(UnsortedMap.toString(), keys);
    }

    System.out.println(sortedMap);
}
```

I am recieving the error below:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

I believe my error is caused by the for() above that I cannot read the Key value.

What adjustment should I make?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So do you want to sort by key or by value? You're taking `keySet` - collection of Strings - and define a Comparator of Integers.

Comment: I think you are trying to convert the `keySet()` (which is a set of `String`s) to a `List<Integer>` in the very first line of code in this method... Maybe you want `UnsortedMap.values()` instead?

Comment: `sortedMap.put(UnsortedMap.toString(), keys);` - what is this supposed to do?

Comment: Btw. in Java 8 and up you can do it in much simplier way using Streams. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27860358/4949750

Comment: Hashmap is probably not the best data structure for it. But you might want to create a treemap using your value as key?

Comment: @deHaar when I put `sortedMap.put(UnsortedMap.values()` it gives  Collection<Integer>  cannot be converted to string error. Thats why I attempted UnsortedMap.toString() but I am pretty sure I am wrong.

Comment: ava sort Map by key (ascending and descending orders). https://howtodoinjava.com/sort/java-sort-map-by-key/

Comment: @Amongalen This is for my data structures class, there is probably a simplier way to do it, but class wants to stick us to the data structures.

Comment: @UtkuTarhan You do know that your map has Strings as keys and Integers as values, right? Because both in your code and comments here it seems like you seem to think the keys are Integers.

Comment: Data structures stay the same, you just use different method to process them. Or did they say you have to implement your own comparator and use for loops?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS so my input format is <String, Integer> when I am comparing I want to sort the integers from high to low. I might have declared that incorrectly as it is the first time I am working with HashKeys.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values), it is about nearly the same problem (plus an additional one).

Comment: @deHaar The answer to the question worked, appreciated the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon the answer came from @deHaar my problem got resolved. The code is below.

```
private static <K, V> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
List<Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Object>() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Comparable<V>) ((Map.Entry<K, V>) (o1)).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry<K, V>) (o2)).getValue());
    }
});

Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Iterator<Entry<K, V>> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry<K, V> entry = (Map.Entry<K, V>) it.next();
    result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

return result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is a comparator that do the job:

```
public class MapKeyByValueComparator<K, T> implements Comparator<K> {

    private final Map<K, T> map;

    private final Comparator<T> comparator;

    public MapKeyByValueComparator(Map<K, T> map, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.map = map;
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(K o1, K o2) {
        int ritem = comparator.compare(map.get(o1), map.get(o2));
        // CAN NOT RETURNS 0, otherwise key with the same value will be overridden
        if (ritem == 0) {
            ritem = 1;
        }
        return ritem;
    }

}
```

And then you can use a `TreeMap` as:

```
Map<something, somethig> map = new TreeMap<>(comparator):
map.addAll(...);
```

But *PAY ATTENTION*, this brokes the contract of *Comparable*

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of the equals method.