# Sort a LinkedHashMap by the value of an nother LinkedHasmap inside it in descending order

Tags: java

This is a repost of my previous post that i closed accidently

I have a LinkedHashMap like this :  `LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>>`
and I want to sort all elemens `text1`, `text2`, etc.... from the first HashMap by the value `amount`, in descending order.

This is what my HashMap look like :

```
{
    text1={
        amount=4847828.0,
        profit=1.6000000000000014
    },
    text2={
        amount=5353757.0, 
        profit=0.7000000000000002
    },
    text3={
        amount=1228950.0,
        profit=11.499999999999996
    },
    text4={
        amount=1446801.0,
        profit=0.2999999999999998
    },
    // long list of 208 elemens
}
```

Is there an "easy" way to do this ?

I found a similar post :[Sorting LinkedHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184378/sorting-linkedhashmap)
But i can't figure how to do the same with a LinkedHashMap inside an another LinkedHashMap.

From my previous post I got this response, but I get java.lang.NullPointerException every time :

```
map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(entry -> entry.getValue().get("amount")))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Do you have some null values of amount?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the line at the bottom actually worked
I just forgot to somewhere turn a `HashMap` to `LinkedHashMap`

The line :

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(entry -> entry.getValue().get("amount")))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e->e.getValue().get("amount")))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,Entry::getValue,
                        (a,b)->b,
                        LinkedHashMap::new
                        ));
```