# Sorting arraylist error?

Tags: android, sorting, collections, arraylist, mismatch

I'm having problem sorting the song list on my music player application. Here's the code:

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
    // get all songs from sdcard
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

    // looping through playlist
    for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsListData.add(song);
        Collections.sort(songsListData); << The problem is in this line
    }

.
.
.
.
.

}
```

It gives out this error:
"Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList>). The inferred type HashMap is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter >"

Can anyone help me fix this? Thanks in advance

EDIT:
So based on Paresh I've changed it to:

```
Collections.sort(songsListData, new myOwnComparator());

public class myOwnComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, String>> {

        public myOwnComparator() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }


        public int compare(HashMap<String, String> o1, HashMap<String, String> o2) {
             return o1.get("KeyName").compareTo(o2.get("KeyName"));
        }
}
```

But it still doesnt work. Here's the log cat:

11-12 12:49:09.450: D/dalvikvm(6584): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 151K, 52% free 2662K/5447K, external 903K/1034K, paused 23ms
11-12 12:49:09.505: D/AndroidRuntime(6584): Shutting down VM
11-12 12:49:09.510: W/dalvikvm(6584): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musicshare/com.example.musicshare.PlayListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at com.example.musicshare.PlayListActivity$myOwnComparator.compare(PlayListActivity.java:103)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at com.example.musicshare.PlayListActivity$myOwnComparator.compare(PlayListActivity.java:1)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:199)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2090)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1965)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at com.example.musicshare.PlayListActivity.onCreate(PlayListActivity.java:61)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
11-12 12:49:09.515: E/AndroidRuntime(6584):     ... 11 more
11-12 12:50:21.790: D/dalvikvm(6717): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 152K, 52% free 2663K/5447K, external 1015K/1034K, paused 52ms
11-12 12:50:21.840: D/AndroidRuntime(6717): Shutting down VM
11-12 12:50:21.850: W/dalvikvm(6717): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musicshare/com.example.musicshare.PlayListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at com.example.musicshare.PlayListActivity$myOwnComparator.compare(PlayListActivity.java:103)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at com.example.musicshare.PlayListActivity$myOwnComparator.compare(PlayListActivity.java:1)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:199)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2090)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1965)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at com.example.musicshare.PlayListActivity.onCreate(PlayListActivity.java:61)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
11-12 12:50:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     ... 11 more

Comment: The problem is the sorting of the hashmap. This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780541/how-to-sort-hash-map may help you

Comment: Store the HashMap values(not the whole HashMap) in a list and than sort the list.

Comment: How to? Sorry I'm not very good in programming yet

Comment: First store it in a list `List<String> strings = song.values()` and then sort the values `Collections.sort(strings)`

Comment: Shouldn't the one sorted be songsListData instead of song? But I've tried changing it into songsListData and it doesnt work (cannot be resolved)

Comment: `songsListData` has the whole HashMap. What do you expect from that sorted HashMap ? I mean generally we sort the Values in the Map and not the key-value pair.

Comment: It still doesnt work. I've edited my question.

Comment: Replace that line with `List<String> songStr = new ArrayList<String>(song.values());`

Comment: Still doesnt work and it makes the application freezes

Answer (score 3):

As you are having `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`, you need to create custom comparator same like:

```
public class myOwnComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, String>> {

    public myOwnComparator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> o1, HashMap<String, String> o2) {
         return o1.get("KeyName").compareTo(o2.get("KeyName"));
    }
}
```

And then apply this comparator to your data:

```
Collections.sort(songsListData, new myOwnComparator());
```

Comment: What do you mean by comparator?

Comment: Hi @Paresh I've tried it but it still is error. Have edited the question.