# How to Sort a keySet by Corresponding Values

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, key-value

*First of all let me say, please dont answer this by saying "just use a TreeMap"*  I am aware of TreeMaps but specifically want to learn if the following is possible.

In Java, lets say I have a HashMap of Strings which map to Doubles.

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

And I have inserted some key value pairs into this map.  Now let's say I get the keySet:

```
Collection<String> keys = map.keySet();
```

My question is, how do I sort the keys collection by the corresponding values in the map?  In Perl this would read something like this:

```
my @keys = sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash;
```

Is there a way to do exactly this in Java using a HashMap?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780541/how-to-sort-hash-map

Comment: even if you mentioned `treemap`, it won't help you (directly) if you want to sort the map by `value` check the link in my above comment.

Comment: @bmorris: how is this a duplicate?  I want to sort the keys of a map by their corresponding values.  That post says to sort a Map.  I want to sort a List