# Java How to return top 10 items based on value in a HashMap

Tags: java, sorting

So I am very new to Java and as such I'm fighting my way through an exercise, converting one of my Python programs to Java.

I have run into an issue where I am trying to replicate the behavior, from python the following will return only the keys sorted (by values), not the values:

```
popular_numbers = sorted(number_dict, key = number_dict.get, reverse = True)
```

In Java,  I have done a bit of research and have not yet found an easy enough sample for a n00b such as myself or a comparable method.  I have found examples using Guava for sorting, but the sort appears to return a HashMap sorted by key.

In addition to the above, one of the other nice things about Python, that I have not found in Java is the ability to, easily, return a subset of the sorted values.  In Python I can simply do the following:

```
print "Top 10 Numbers: %s" % popular_numbers[:10]
```

In this example, number_dict is a dictionary of key,value pairs where key represents numbers 1..100 and the value is the number of times the number (key) occurs:

```
for n in numbers:
 if not n == '':
   number_dict[n] += 1
```

The end result would be something like:

> Top 10 Numbers: ['27', '11', '5', '8', '16', '25', '1', '24', '32',
>   '20']

To clarify, in Java I have successfully created a HashMap, I have successfully examined numbers and increased the values of the key,value pair.  I am now stuck at the sort and return the top 10 numbers (keys) based on value.

Comment: Is there a reason for using `HashMap`, particularly since you need sorting?

Comment: Have you thought about using a tree map rather than a hash map?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780541/how-to-sort-hash-map , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values

Comment: @TheNewIdiot well, that sorts the keys, not the values

Comment: "top 10 numbers based on value"? What do you mean?

Comment: No particular reason, HashMap is what I found that most closely resembled a Python Dictionary. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Top 10 numbers refers to the numbers (keys) who have occurred most frequently in a list of numbers read in.  So for a very basic example, I initialize a dictionary of sorts, {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}.  Given a list of numbers [3,2,2,3,1,2] I would have at the end {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2}.  When sorted by values I would have popular_numbers = [2, 3, 1].

Answer (score 10):

1. Put the map's [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) into a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).
2. Sort this list using [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which sorts [`Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)s based on their values.
3. Use the [`subList(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method of `List` to retrieve a new list containing the top 10 elements.

Yes, it will be much more verbose than Python :)

Comment: Yeah this is the way to go. But then what was the point of using `HashMap`? Especially when the result is ordered by *value*? I don't know what the OP is doing...

Answer (score 4):

With Java 8+, to get the first 10 elements of a list of intergers:

```
list.stream().sorted().limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To get the first 10 elements of a map's keys, that are integers:

```
map.keySet().stream().sorted().limit(10).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), map::get));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your map is defined something like this and that you want to sort based on **values**:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
//add values
Collection<Integer> values= map.values();
ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>(values);
Collections.sort(list);
```

Now, print the first top 10 elements of the list.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

The values in the map are not actually sorted, because the `HashMap` is not sorted at all (it stores the values in the buckets based on the hashCode of the key). This code is just displaying 10 smallest elements in the map.

**EDIT** sort without loosing the key-value pairs:

```
//sorted tree map
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tree= new TreeMap<>();

//iterate over a map
Iteartor<Integer> it= map.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Integer key= it.next();
    tree.put(map.get(key), key);
}
```

Now you have the `TreeMap` tree that is sorted and has reversed key-value pairs from the original map, so you don't lose the information.

Comment: Now you've lost the key-value pairings

Comment: This sorts by the values, but doesn't let you easily look them up to see which key they referred to...

Comment: Yes the binding is lost, but it will work if you only need the first top 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap`s aren't ordered in Java, and so there isn't really a good way to order them short of a brute-force search through all the keys. Try using `TreeMap`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: `TreeMap` sorts based on keys not values.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Map for store the numbers
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    // Populate the map ...

    // Sort by the more popular number
    Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();
    List<Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<Integer, Integer> a,
                Entry<Integer, Integer> b) {
            return b.getValue() - a.getValue();
        }
    });


    // Output the top 10 numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue())` in the comparison. The OP's example uses integers, but if they decided to put some floating points in, just changing the types would break this code.

Comment: The `value` is the **popularity** of a number (number may be floating). In other words, the **frequency**.

Comment: Alright, I see that in this case it will just be integers. However, I'd still stick with my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Guava [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) is a great fit for your use case, and would nicely replace your HashMap.  It is a collection which counts the number of occurences of each element.

Multisets has a method [copyHighestCountFirst](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#copyHighestCountFirst%28com.google.common.collect.Multiset%29), which returns an immutable Multiset ordered by count.

Now some code:

```
Multiset<Integer> counter = HashMultiset.create();
//add Integers 
ImmutableMultiset<Integer> sortedCount = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(counter);
//iterate through sortedCount as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SortedMap`, call `values()`. The docs indicate the following:

`The collection's iterator returns the values in ascending order of the corresponding keys`

So as long as your comparator is written correctly you can just iterate over the first `n` keys

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a list from the keyset.
2. Sort the HashMap by values using the keys to access the value in the Collection.sort() method.
3. Return a sub list of the sorted key set.
4. if you care about the values, you can use the keys in step 3 and build value set.

   HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   List list = new ArrayList(hashMap.keySet());
   Collections.sort(list, (w1, w2) -> hashMap.get(w2) - hashMap.get(w1)); //sorted descending order by value;

   return list.subList(0, 10);

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the ranking order and efficiently return top count, much smaller than the size of the map size:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .limit(count)
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (e1, e2) -> e1,
                    LinkedHashMap::new))
```