# Arrange hashmap in a certain order

Tags: java

Let's say I have a hashmap as below

```
Map<String,List<String>> nameMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

Also I already have the following key values in the hashmap

Martin - 1
Julia - 3
Andrew - 2
Steve - 5

Now The question is I have a particular order which I need the hashmap to hold and when I print out the entries in the map it should print in the order I need.

The order I need is

Julia - 3
Andrew - 2
Steve - 5
Martin - 1

I know I can use linked hashmap to preserve the order. but my original one is a Hashmap and how do I arrange it in the order I need?

Comment: In what is your criteria to order based, if you don't explain, it just looks random to me.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time." In short, you don't want to just rely on hashmap alone to get you a certain order. You're going to need to bring some other things into play.

Comment: You can't order a HashMap - the entries are arranged according to the hash value of the key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780541/how-to-sort-hash-map

Comment: If there exist a fixed criteria that you can apply for sorting you can use Collections.sort(list, comparator); to sort the elements in the order you want. list is your list that you want to sort and comparator is a class that implements Comparator interface.

Comment: @Marcelo : there is no criteria. I just need it in the order that I just mentioned. I don't mind if it can be hardcoded or something like that

Comment: The answer to questions like this is always "HashMap order is random; use LinkedHashMap". Since you already know both those facts, I don't know what more you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `HashMap` is unsorted, and because it cannot be sorted in place due to the way that it is constructed <sup>*</sup>, you have two simple options here:

- Create a `LinkedHashMap`, and populate it with the data from your original `HashMap` in the desired order, or
- Cereate a temporary list from the `keySet` of your `HashMap`, order it as desired, and then iterate that sorted set, and retrieve the data from the original `HashMap` in the desired order.

  ---

  <sup>*</sup> `HashMap` entries are arranged in "buckets" according to their hash code, which is very much arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is unordered. You can use LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is unordered colection(the items are ordered by the hash and you can't rely on that). You can use TreeMap.