# Sorting HashMap on values of type List

Tags: list, sorting, hashmap

I have a map with keys as String and values as a List, Need to sort the map on values

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> data = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```

Where List is of size 3 and need to sort on item1, item2 and then item3 of list in asc order

for example if i have a map  like below

```
K1=[3, 1, 96], 
K2=[0, 4, 4], 
K3=[3, 2, 88], 
K4=[2, 2, 12], 
K5=[3, 3, 64], 
K6=[2, 4, 12], 
K7=[3, 4, 64], 
K8=[2, 1, 12], 
K9=[2, 3, 12],
K10=[1, 2, 33],
K11=[3, 1, 45],
K12=[1, 1, 12],
K13=[0, 1, 6],
K14=[0, 1, 3],
K15=[2, 1, 12],
K16=[3, 4, 22],
```

After Sort :

```
K14=[0, 1, 3],
K13=[0, 1, 6],
K2=[0, 4, 4], 
K12=[1, 1, 12],
K10=[1, 2, 33],
K8=[2, 1, 12],
K15=[2, 1, 12],
K4=[2, 2, 12],
K9=[2, 3, 12],
K6=[2, 4, 12],
K11=[3, 1, 45],
K1=[3, 1, 96],
K3=[3, 2, 88],
K5=[3, 3, 64],
K16=[3, 4, 22],
K7=[3, 4, 64]
```

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a HashMap in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780541/how-to-sort-a-hashmap-in-java) - Also worth mentioning that you can't sort a HashMap. It's a Map, it has no sorting order. It's a Set of values with no order guarantee.

Comment: Neither a HashMap nor a TreeMap can be sorted on values(a HashMap can't be sorted at all, and TreeMap only on keys) so you would have to transfer it to some other data structure. What needs do you have for your data structure?

Comment: I basically have a list of 4 items [id,type,value1,value2] and I have to sort them based on type, value1 and value2. How can this best be done

Comment: @user3008823 In that case, see my updated answer.

Comment: Of the 4 items id is String and rest are integers, its not a List of just Integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that you transfer your elements to a `List<Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>>>` (for example by calling `new ArrayList<>(data.entrySet())`) which can then be sorted using a `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>>>`.

The horrible parameter types can of course be simplified for example if you don't need the map keys.

It would go something like this(at least in Java 8. Java 7 would require slightly more boilerplate code):

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>>> dataList;
dataList = new ArrayList<>(data.entrySet());
dataList.sort((x, y) -> {
    int comparison = Integer.compare(x.getValue().get(0), y.getValue().get(0));
    if (comparison != 0) return comparison;
    comparison = Integer.compare(x.getValue().get(1), y.getValue().get(1));
    if (comparison != 0) return comparison;
    return Integer.compare(x.getValue().get(2), y.getValue().get(2));
});
```

Edit: If you just want to sort a `List<List<Integer>> list` it gets as simple as this(Java 7 this time):

```java
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<List<Integer>>(){
    public int compare(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        int comparison = a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0));
        if (comparison != 0) return comparison;
        comparison = a.get(1).compareTo(b.get(1));
        if (comparison != 0) return comparison;
        return a.get(2).compareTo(b.get(2));
    }
});
```