# Sorting in java for Map?

Tags: comparator, comparable

---

*As we use Collections.sort(list) for Collection but can we able to use that in the case of map like by implementing Comparable and Comparator? Or we can just do iterator over a Map in java?*

========================================================================

Comment: Make a minimal effort to search before you ask. E.g., [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java), [How to sort a HashMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780541/how-to-sort-a-hashmap-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important feature of a list is that there is an order to the elements, whereas within a Map there is no such order. Therefore it doesn't make sense to sort a Map. If order is important to you, you really should be using a list.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose, we can use a treemap. Each entry we insert are automatically sorted

For the treemap to sort, you have to implement the comparable or comparator in the object(key) that you wish to put in treemap

Check out this link
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html