# How to sort Hashmap of type Hashmap<String, Arraylist<String>> by value?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I want to sort the following hashmap by value. Hashmap is `Hashmap<String, Arraylist<String>>` and the data in it is as following:

```
924911637601767=[1, John]  
864467483673342=[2, Paul]  
825398867568656=[8, James]  
1034643283235161=[5,Elina]
```

I want to sort the above data with respect to the counter values i.e 1,2,8,5
**After Sorting**

```
924911637601767=[1, John]  
864467483673342=[2, Paul]   
1034643283235161=[5,Elina]  
825398867568656=[8, James]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hashmap abstract data type is inherently unsorted. Depending on your use case, you could do something like:

```
import java.util.*;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("924911637601767", Arrays.asList("1", "John"));
        map.put("864467483673342", Arrays.asList("2", "Paul"));
        map.put("825398867568656", Arrays.asList("8", "James"));
        map.put("1034643283235161", Arrays.asList("5", "Elina"));

        List<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>>(map.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> l1, Map.Entry<String,List<String>> l2) {
                return l1.getValue().get(0).compareTo(l2.getValue().get(0));
            }
        });

        for (Map.Entry<String,List<String>> e : entries) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : [" + e.getValue().get(0)
                                          + ", " + e.getValue().get(1) + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But in case i have values more then i mentioned it is not sorting those values correctly.

Comment: Thanks A lot i got using this what i want.. :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) no guarantees as to the order.

If you want get list by order like you want, you should sort list values of the HashMap.

Example can be found here [How to sort a HashMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780541/how-to-sort-a-hashmap-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it >does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. 
>   See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

In other words, what you are looking for cannot be achieved as you want.

However, what you can do is to transform your Hashmap to a list of objects that consist of each map entry elements.
Object: key, name, number for example.
Your object can then implement java.lang.Comparable in order to sort it as you want.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the sortedMap Interface if you are interested in sorted order and also want to keep a map. 
TreeMap could be a choice.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html