# sorting hashMap by value and returning the list

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to find a sorted list based on distance. (Lowest to highest)
Restaurants and customer has lat and lng in database. I am getting them from database and comparing between them and trying to display a list of restaurants which is closest to the customer.

Here is my code

```
//ALGORITHOM
    public ArrayList<String> displayNearestRestaurant(String customerId) throws SQLException{
      //arraylist variable  
      ArrayList<String> restaurantList = new ArrayList<String>();

      //array to store all distance
      ArrayList<Map<String, String>> distanceList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

      //grab customerId
      Customer ob = new Customer();
      //find lat and lng 
      String latStr =ob.getCustomerLat(customerId);
      String lngStr =ob.getCustomerLng(customerId);

      //convert to double
      double customerLat = Double.parseDouble(latStr);
      double customerLng = Double.parseDouble(lngStr);

      //ok we found customer lat and lng

      //now start loop and all restaurants available 
       con = new DBconnection().Connect(); //connects the db
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
       query = "SELECT * FROM restauranttable";
       rs = st.executeQuery(query);
       //starting loop
       while (rs.next()) {
           String restaurantId = rs.getString("restaurant_id");
           String dbLatStr = rs.getString("lat");
           double dbLat = Double.parseDouble(dbLatStr);

           String dbLngStr = rs.getString("lng");
           double dbLng = Double.parseDouble(dbLngStr);
           //this.CalculateDistance(customerLat, customerLng, dbLat, dbLng, "M");
           double dist = calculateDistance.distance(customerLat, customerLng, dbLat, dbLng, "M");
           //double to string conversion
           String strDist = Double.toString(dist);

           // insert restaurantId and its distance against the customer position in a array
            Map<String, String> distanceL = new HashMap<String, String>();
            distanceL.put("restaurantId", restaurantId);
            distanceL.put("distance",strDist);
            distanceList.add(distanceL);
            //I am lost at this point  
        }

        con.close();
        //now distanceList has all distance and restaurant id stored...
        // now process the distanceList restaurant id and and value
        //find add to the restaurant to the list which has smallest value


       //now check the distanceL list 
      return restaurantList;
    }
```

Now as you can see distanceList is suppose to hold restaurant id and the distance. I am not sure how to sort them and return the restaurantList based on lowest to highest distance. Please help me to figure this out

Comment: You actually can't sort a `HashMap`. Please, consider using other data structure (like `LinkedHashMap`).

Comment: Could you kindly show me how its done using the same code... :)

Comment: @NurulAlamAnik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780541/how-to-sort-a-hashmap-in-java You can't directly do it without making a different data structure.

Comment: so linkedHashMap is the solution?