# Why doesn't hashmap sort correctly?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I want to sort my HashMap by key. But it could not sort correctly. Any idea?

Thank you

My full code

like following :

```
private static Map<String, Integer> allList = new HashMap<>();
public static String factors(int n) {
    // your code
    for(int i=2;i<n/2;i++){
        getPrimes(n, i);
    }

    Map<String, Integer> result2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();        
    allList.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .forEachOrdered(x -> result2.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
    String result="";
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : result2.entrySet()) {

        if(entry.getValue()>1)
        {
            result = result+"("+entry.getKey()+"**"+entry.getValue()+")";
        }
        else result=result+ "("+entry.getKey()+")";
    }

    return result2;
}

public static Map<String,Integer> getPrimes(int n, int divide)
{
   //part code of put element to allList

}


public static boolean isPrime(int num)
{
        ....
}
```

when I looked result2 like following and not sorted.

[image: result2]

Comment: a hash map is not sorted use a `TreeMap` instead

Comment: I used TreeMap also, but it didn't sort.

Comment: override tostring and hashcode method

Comment: A `TreeMap` should sort, so you should get the lexicographic key order: 11, 17, 2, 3, 5, 7. What did you get instead?

Comment: [Works for me](https://ideone.com/KTPCJy). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, with full code (including imports) and output (as **text**).

Comment: Your screen shot doesn’t look right. The map values should have type `Integer` but are rendered with quotes around them. Are you sure it shows that map??

Comment: Your screenshot shows `allList` not `result2`. Also streams should be stateless, so instead of modifying map outside of it, let stream create and return LinkedHashMap like https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455817

Comment: Voting to close because the problem can't be reproduced as it's just a typographical error

Comment: I cannot reproduce either. I get a `LinkedHashMap` of `{11=2, 17=1, 2=2, 3=3, 5=1, 7=1}`.

Comment: Please note that when sorting strings they are sorted as strings, not as numbers. So `17` comes before `2` because the char `1` comes before the char `2`.

Comment: ***Some confusions here***. Your code worked, but in the debugger a (Linked)HashMap lists its values still unordered. The LinkedHashMap is filled in order, so iterating over it will be ordered too. Of course String makes the ordering alphanumeric, 1 < 17 < 2.

Comment: Sorry, your full code adds to the confusion rather than resolving it. [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. Note: minimal.'

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate since the title is wrong but the question, once read, is about an algo, and incorrect interpretation. Shame on all those who marked as dup. The right answer is that he is still looking at allList and not result2.

Comment: Sorry pict is allList. I added new one.

Comment: Thanks for your new linked image. It confirms what we’ve said: the map *is* sorted by the string keys in lexicographic (not numeric) order.

Comment: Allright Ole, but how can I solve problem? I want to sort just :)

Comment: Does the key have to stay a String?

Comment: *how can I solve problem?* (1) Use `Integer` keys rather than strings; or (2) [How do I sort string of numbers in ascending order?](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-sort-string-of-numbers-in-ascending-order/)

Comment: After changed following code works. thanks>> I use Integer key and for sorted I've used : allList.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .forEachOrdered(x -> result2.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));

Answer (score 4):

Your key is a String this sorts differently than an Integer. With the limited information provided I think the problem lies there.